# loading javascript with variable parameter in src-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-trends

I try to make a Google Trends charts with responsive width. But it wont work. It is loading the URL like it should be. When I try to load the external JavaScript, no chart appears on my page. Can anyone help me or give me a hint please?

Here is my code:

```
<h1>Google Trends</h1>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

  var chartwidth = ($('.content').innerWidth());

  $(function () {
   $('<script>')
    .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
    .attr('src',  '//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenbesitzkarte,+waffenpass,+waffenschein&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=' + chartwidth + '&h=330')
    .replaceAll('#chartA');
  });

  $(function () {
   $('<script>')
   .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
   .attr('src',  '//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenrecht,+waffengesetz,+waffenbesitz&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=' + chartwidth + '&h=330')
   .replaceAll('#chartB');
  });

 });
</script>

<div id="chartA"></div>

<div id="chartB"></div>
```

Here is my updated code:

```
<h1>Google Trends</h1>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

  var chartwidth = ($('.content').innerWidth());

  $.getScript('//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenbesitzkarte,+waffenpass,+waffenschein&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=' + chartwidth + '&h=330', function(data){
   $('#chartA').append(data);
  });

  $.getScript('//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenrecht,+waffengesetz,+waffenbesitz&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=' + chartwidth + '&h=330', function(data){
   $('#chartB').append(data);
  });

 });

</script>

<div id="chartA"></div>

<div id="chartB"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating a `jQuery` object of a `<script>` tag and you are not insterting in to DOM. If you want to include an external JS file and you are using jQuery then do

```
 $.getScript("yourScript.js", function(){
    // Callback when script is completely loaded.
 });
```

In your case, do:

```
$.getScript('//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenbesitzkarte,+waffenpass,+waffenschein&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=' + chartwidth + '&h=330', function(){

});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i changed the code (look above) but it is still not working. i get the success note when i add the status parameter in the function, but when i want to append the data Parameter, nothing happens.

Comment: the data parameter outputs "undefined" in an alert()

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=de&q=waffenbesitzkarte,+waffenpass,+waffenschein&geo=AT&date=today+24-m&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-1&tz=Etc/GMT-1&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=400&h=330
will return a javascript code snippet, which tries to do document.write. You are trying to load the javascript asynchronously($.getScript) and browsers don't allow asynchronously-loaded external script to write into a document.

What you can do is load the script of google charts by adding script tag with src same as you are loading using getScript().

Hope this helps!

Comment: i just tried it like this: $('#chartA').append('<scr' + 'ipt>' + data + '</scr' + 'ipt>'); but it wont work anyways - same result